# how start new tmux session with shell code?

Tags: zsh, tmux, fzf

I want to fuzzy find a file and then open it in a new tmux window.

Unfortunately, the tmux session exits immediately, and returns a 0 exit code. If I echo the command and run it from terminal manually, it works fine. Similarly, if I copy the output of echo and make it it's own command, yy, I can execute that and it works fine too.

Another (bonus) problem appears to happen when using ZLE because it doesn't seem to set the terminal. While xx will return a 0 exit code (immediately), ctrl-x will return the warning 'not a terminal' from tmux.

```
xx () {
  P=$(zsh -c $FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND | fzf +m)                                     
  CMD="'cd $(dirname $P) && ${EDITOR:-vim} $(basename $P)'"                     
  echo tmux new-session $CMD                                                    
  tmux new-session $CMD
}

yy () {                                                                         
  tmux new-session 'cd /data/repos/notes && nvim engineering_a_compiler.md'                                                                           
}

# create zsh widgets
zle -N xx xx
# keybind zsh widgets
bindkey ^x xx
```

Tried following stuff in other stack overflow post [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17116/prevent-pane-window-from-closing-when-command-completes-tmux/17121#17121)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who is interested, here are the relevant parts of my .zshrc_fzf configuration; the tl;dr is I don't use widgets and instead call functions directly with text bindkeys, since it seems that ZLE doesn't pass the tty on to functions executed in widgets.

This file maps ctrl+p to fuzzy find a file using `fd`, change to the containing directory, and open it in an editor. If you're not in a tmux session, it does the same after opening a tmux session (in addition to changing to the project directory before starting the tmux session so it's the root of all future tmux-panes in that session).

It does the same thing with ctrl+f, but uses ripgrep (`rg`) to search for a file by file contents instead.

not defined in this file: `source_if_exists() { if [ -f $1 ]; then source $1; fi }`

```
#!/usr/bin/zsh
# SOURCE: https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/wiki/examples
source_if_exists /usr/share/fzf/key-bindings.zsh
source_if_exists /usr/share/fzf/completion.zsh

FZF_PREVIEW="'head -100 {}'"
FZF_VIM_PLUGIN_PREVIEW=~/.local/share/nvim/plugged/fzf.vim/bin/preview.sh
if [[ -f $FZF_VIM_PLUGIN_PREVIEW ]]; then
  FZF_PREVIEW=$FZF_VIM_PLUGIN_PREVIEW
fi
FZF_DEFAULT_OPTS="--layout=reverse --height='40%' --preview='"$FZF_PREVIEW" {}'"
export FZF_RIPGREP_OPTS="--column --line-number --no-heading --hidden --ignore-file $HOME/.gitignore_global"
export FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND="fd . $SEARCH_DIRS --hidden --ignore-file ~/.gitignore_global"
FZF_CTRL_T_COMMAND=$FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND

edit () {
  P=$1
  # file
  if [[ -f $P ]]; then
    if [[ $TERM != tmux* ]]; then  # not in tmux session
      # change to project directory, becomes root of new tmux-panes
      cd $(dirname $P)
      if [[ $(git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree 2>/dev/null) == "true" ]]; then
        cd $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)
      fi
      tmux new-session "cd $(dirname $P) && ${EDITOR:-vim} $(basename $P); zsh"
      clear
    else  # within existing tmux session
      cd $(dirname $P) && ${EDITOR:-vim} $(basename $P)
    fi
  # directory
  elif [[ -d $P ]]; then
    cd $P
  fi
}

# find path, change to directory, if path is a file, open in $EDITOR
fd_find () {
  edit $(zsh -c $FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND | fzf +m)
}

rg_find () {
  CMD="rg $FZF_RIPGREP_OPTS ${1:-'.*'} $SEARCH_DIRS"
  edit $(zsh -c $CMD | fzf +m | cut -d: -f1)
}

# zsh shortcuts
bindkey -s ^p 'fd_find\n'
bindkey -s ^f 'rg_find\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with how you are defining `CMD`. The hard-coded `tmux` command would be (using the `-c` option to simplify things)

```
tmux new-session -c "$(dirname "$P")" "${EDITOR:-vim} "$(basename "$P")"
```

To make store the command and its arguments, use an array.

```
xx () {
  P=$(zsh -c "$FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND" | fzf +m)
  CMD=("${EDITOR:-vim}" "$(basename "$P")")
  echo "tmux new-session ${CMD[*]}"
  tmux new-session -c "$(dirname "$P")" "${CMD[@]}"
}
```

Comment: So the -c flag doesn't work with new-session, at least with tmux 3.1b; I've posted my solution below

Comment: How is it not working? `tmux new-session -c /usr/local/bin` gives me a shell whose working directory is `/usr/local/bin` rather than `$HOME`.

Comment: It's not obvious why you need to change the working directory at all; isn't `tmux new-session vim "$P"` sufficient?

Comment: So, for example; `tmux new-session -c "cd /"` exits immediately after completing the command in the new session; same with `tmux new-session -c cd /; zsh`; the quoted version, `tmux new-session -c "cd /; zsh"`, doesn't actually execute the code  in quotes in the new session. Without `-c`, it works, so `tmux new-session "cd /; zsh"` works fine (maybe it's a version thing?).

The reason I cd to the directory is so that when I exit, I am in the containing directory, which is almost always what I want, i.e. in the project directory of the file I just edited.